# Disable input on dropdown change, works in fiddle but not on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery

NOTE: This is not an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error!

I have some code that disables the postage input field when someone selects `Collection Only`.

You can see it working on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sZrLh/

Here is the JavaScript on the site with alerts to see whats happening:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $("#postage_dropdown").change(function(){
        if($("#postage_dropdown").val() == "6"){
            $("#postage").prop('disabled', true);
            alert("1");
        }else{
            $("#postage").prop('disabled', false);
            alert("2");
        }
        alert("3");
    });
    alert("4");
</script>
```

No when putting it onto my site it doesn't seem to work.
Look here: https://secure1918.hostgator.com/~innoedge/sell.php

Why doesn't it work? I'm not getting any errors, using `jQuery 1.8.2`.
All the other errors are Facebook and the annoying adverts.

Comment: What do you mean by all the errors are facebook?

Comment: There are 4 errors from the Facebook JS SDK

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced weird errors with this too... have you tried using

```
$("#postage").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

and

```
$("#postage").attr('disabled', '');
```

?
Might be worth a try - I found that some seemed to work, some didn't

Comment: It seems that $("#postage_dropdown").change isn't being called because I don't get an alert(3)